# Adding a column to a dataframe in pandas based on text in files (Python)

Tags: python, text, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column consisting of a bunch of document numbers, all of which follow the same format, like so:

```
id  doc
0   A/BC/998
1   A/BC/999
2   A/BC/1000
3   A/BC/1001
4   A/BC/1002
```

In addition, I have a directory with two subdirectories - folder0 and folder1 - containing roughly 700 .txt files each. Each .txt file corresponds to a document the number of which is given in the data frame. The .txt files have randomly numbered filenames (e.g., N12345.txt); the contents of each file contain the document number (e.g., "Document number A/BC/998, approved on 31 December 2012").

I'm trying to figure out a way to add a column to my dataframe that would have a 0 if the document is in folder0 and a 1 if it's in folder1. It should look something like this:

```
id  doc         category
0   A/BC/998        0
1   A/BC/999        1
2   A/BC/1000       1
3   A/BC/1001       0
4   A/BC/1002       0
```

To do this, I'd need to read the contents of each document and match against the "doc" series in my dataframe.

Thus far I have the following:

```
for filename in glob.glob('path/to/folder0/*.txt'):
    for line in open(filename):
        ***pseudocode***
        if contents of line from file match contents of Series 'doc':
           write 0 to new Series 'category'
```

I'm stuck on translating the pseudocode to actual python. What would be the best way to do this?

Note: there may be more document numbers in the dataframe than there are .txt files; for anything that isn't in folder0 or folder1, I'd like to write NaN values and then just drop those from the final dataframe.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what if it is in both?

Comment: Padraic - do you mean what if the file is in both folders? I've set it up so that it wouldn't be - it's either in one or the other.

Comment: I meant for instance   `A/BC/998` was in a line in a file in both folders

Comment: Given the structure of the text documents, that wouldn't happen - it would only be found in one file, and each file could only be in one folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think your pseudo code would work:

```
df['category'] = np.nan
```

And then your code with enhancements:

```
for i in xrange(2):
    for filename in glob.glob('path/to/folder' + str(i) + '/*.txt'):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                list_words = line.split(' ')
                df[df['doc'] == list_words[2]]['category'] = i
```

P.S. I did this from my phone so let me know if it works, otherwise I'll test it and correct it tomorrow morning :3

Comment: Hmm, not quite - it's not spitting out any errors, but it isn't filling the category column with any values, either. Could this be because we're setting == line here? In my 'doc' column, I have values like A/BC/123, and in the actual .txt files, the lines in question are something like "Document number A/BC/123 filed on December 1, 2009"... I don't know enough about how the glob module works to determine whether that's the problem, though. In any case, thank you!

Comment: Not sure what happened to your second comment - I tried the edited code as well, and with the index value for list_words set to 2 it gave me a "list index out of range" error... After running just the first five lines of code, I checked what list_words[0] would spit out by itself, and it gave me the last word of the first file in the folder. List_words[1] gave me another list index out of range error. Is there something happening with the split? Can't quite figure this out, but I feel like I'm really close - all the more frustrating. 

In any event, thanks again! Will keep working on this.